# Labeling edges in Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

I want to make a graph of the mother nuclides of all Tin Isotopes. I found this

```
g = Graph[Union@Flatten[
 Thread[DirectedEdge @@ ##] & /@ 
  Select[{#, IsotopeData[#, "DaughterNuclides"]} & /@ 
    IsotopeData[], #[[2]] != {} &]]];
```

and that

```
g1 = Union[Flatten[VertexComponent[g, #] & /@ #], #] &@{Entity[
 "Isotope", "Tin112"], Entity["Isotope", "Tin114"], 
Entity["Isotope", "Tin115"], Entity["Isotope", "Tin116"], 
Entity["Isotope", "Tin117"], Entity["Isotope", "Tin118"], 
Entity["Isotope", "Tin119"], Entity["Isotope", "Tin120"], 
Entity["Isotope", "Tin122"], Entity["Isotope", "Tin124"]};
```

and a labelling function for vertices:

```
vf[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] :=Block[{},{Black, 
Background -> 
 If[StringCases[IsotopeData[name, "StandardName"], 
    "Tin"] == {"Tin"}, LightRed, LightBlue], 
Inset[IsotopeData[name, "FullSymbol"], {xc, yc}]}];
```

Now I was able to make this:

```
g2 = Subgraph[g, g1, VertexShapeFunction -> vf, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", AspectRatio -> 2]
```

Now, how can I add DecayModeSymbols as a label for the graph edges? And best would be if I can switch them off individually where it gets too crowdy.

Comment: Have a look at `EdgeLabels` and `EdgeShapeFunction`.

Comment: thanks, I already looked at those. But I was unable to create some kind of list with the properties from the existing graph. But as far as I understood such a list is needed for EdgeLabels or EdgeShapeFunction.